# AVPlayer smooth transition between videos

Tags: swift, avplayer

I have a video player, that plays video url's parsed from json file. Everything works fine, except there is no smooth transition between the videos. I made the back-ground black (as recommended in one of the stack answers) but still don't like the short flash in-between.

Is there a way to fix this with a fade-in / fade - out for swift? I tried to implement AVQueuePlayer but I don't understand how to implement it in my code and don't understand how it works.

Please if any one knows a solution for smooth transition that would be great. The same questions asked on stack are either never answered or contain really old answers/solutions.

EDIT: 
My video is being played through the AVPlayerViewController. The video URL is for a mp4 video.

Comment: I think you can capture an image from video URL and assign it as a background to your View and you can add `AVPlayer` layer to this image. i think it can solve your problem of black background

Comment: The problem with making an image background is the fact that it's to much work. The purpose is to just keep adding mp4 url to the json. So when you have like 10 short video's you don't need to create an image of all videos individualy

Answer (score 1):

You can fade out the player view, change the video, and then fade in the player view.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: {
    self.playerView.alpha = 0
}, completion: { _ in
    self.playerView.loadUrl...// Update video

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1) {
        self.playerView.alpha = 1
    }
})
```

Comment: I have an AVPlayerViewController, is it possible to use your example for this?

Comment: Yeah, just change `self.playerView` the view of the player view controller.

Comment: The error I get with your code is: "Value of type 'AVPlayerViewController' has no member 'alpha'".